# Is there a good GUI to generate XSLT

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xslt

I have a complicated XML output that I want to make pretty  by using XSLT.

I have created XSLT by hand, and I hate it.  It's so picky I get frustrated creating it by hand.

Is there any kind of GUI that can help me generate XSLT?  Preferably, something that I can plug in an XML file and start working on.

Thanks

Comment: Asking for software recommendations are clearly not welcome on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altova XML Spy and Stylus Studio both have graphical tools that generate XSLT. I hate them - I can never remember what all the squiggly icons mean, and I can never understand the semantics of the diagrams. Give me text any day. But if GUI programming appeals to you, then perhaps you should give them a try.

Answer (score 1):

[Oxygen's XSLT editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xslt_editor.html) is very good.

Comment: I agree, though I'm not sure it's an answer to the question, a "GUI to generate XSLT."